# Updating records with SQL statement that are in 2 diff. tables not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is my SQL statement:

```
UPDATE sysdba.CONTACT, sysdba.ADDRESS
SET sysdba.ADDRESS.Address1 = '123 Tech Parway'
WHERE sysdba.CONTACT.AddressID = sysdba.ADDRESS.AddressID
AND sysdba.CONTACT.contactID = 'CRBD'
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TSQL solution

```
UPDATE sysdba.ADDRESS
SET Address1 = '123 Tech Parway'
FROM sysdba.ADDRESS
INNER JOIN sysdba.CONTACT 
    ON sysdba.CONTACT.AddressID = sysdba.ADDRESS.AddressID
WHERE sysdba.CONTACT.contactID = 'CRBD'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem with this syntax according to [MySQL UPDATE command reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html). Maybe you're getting errors from MSSQLServer? Could you supply the errors for further investigation?